# Equalizer application for Android using AudioTrack?

Tags: android, filtering, signal-processing, audiotrack

I want to create an equalizer using Android. The app should load a .mp3 from the SDcard; apply some audio filtering and playback the filtered audio in (as close to) real time and also save the filtered  audio.

Filtering the audio with a IIR low-pass, band-pass and high-pass filters. I have calculated the filter coefficients in matlab and stored them in matrices in java. The app will have 3 sliders which alter the gain for each of the three filers (the gain value will be multiplied by the "b" coefficients).

I was thinking of trying this method but am not entirely sure if this is the way to go about it:

1. Load and decode/convert .mp3 file to PCM using JLayer (for sample data).
2. Take PCM samples in a buffer and filter using Matlabs "filter" function (the Java equivalent).
3. Use AudioTrack to playback filtered audio.

Is this the right way to go?